# USB device not acknowledged

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, usb

I have a USB device (a new "B-L072Z-LRWAN1" demo board from ST Micro)

When I plug it in the board boots and LEDs start blinking, but ubuntu (18.04.3 LTS) does not react at all.

The board never appears in the `lsusb` listing.

I've tried both USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports.

I have run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` while plugging and unplugging it, and there is no activity.

I have followed the [directions](https://hackaday.io/project/35169-hackable-cmwx1zzabz-lora-devices/log/79458-initial-drop-of-alpha-arduino-core) for copying the *.rules files to `/etc/udev/rules.d`, but that doesn't make a difference

I have tried multiple USB cables (thinking it was a broken data wire), with no luck.

I'm getting tired of spinning my wheels on this. Anyone have a suggestion of where to poke and prod next?

Comment: What `dmesg` says..

Comment: @SHW running ```watch "dmesg | tail -5"``` while plugging and unplugging the board shows no activity. (as a test, if I plug and unplug a random USB<->Blutetooth device I have, I DO see activity in dmesg.)